# How to correctly scale the coordinates of a rectangle based on the length and width ratio

Tags: python, math, geometry

I have four coordinates for rectangle in `df` table:

| lat1 | lon1 | lat2 | lon2 | lat3 | lon3 | lat4 | lon4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 51.071833 | 6.237204 | 51.071836 | 6.237195 | 51.071833 | 6.237195 | 51.071836 | 6.237204 |

Where P1 = (lat1, lon1) and P2 = (lat2, lon2).

When we draw, it will be exactly red rectangle from picture:

[image]

Right now, I would like to re-scale red rectangle to **pink rectangle**.
I know that rectangle has to be 94*8mm wide​ and 8mm high. So the ratio between length​ and width is 1/94.

With this information I need calculate exact position (pink rectangle) of the other​ corners. Points P1 and P2 are the vertices of the diagonal of the rectangle, so they do not change.

Based on another problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109122/how-do-i-calculate-the-new-x-y-coordinates-and-width-height-of-a-re-sized-group, I tried this:

```
df['new_lat3'] = df['lat1'] + (1/94)*(df['lat3'] - df['lat1'])
df['new_lon3'] = df['lon1'] + (94)*(df['lon3'] - df['lon1'])
df['new_lat4'] = df['lat2'] + (1/94)*(df['lat4'] - df['lat2'])
df['new_lon4'] = df['lon2'] + (94)*(df['lon4'] - df['lon2'])
```

Do you think this is a good direction?

Thank you in advance for your advices.

Answer (score 1):

The diagonal (black line) is the hypothenuse of the triangle formed by the sides of your pink rectangle.  From the Pythagorean theorem we know that `D^2 = H^2 + W^2` where D is the length of the diagonal and H, W are the width and height of the pink rectangle respectively.  We also know the relation between H an W: `H = W/94`.  A little algebra should give us the formula to scale the rectangle based on the length of the black line.

```
D^2 = H^2 + W^2
H   = W/94

D^2 = (W/94)^2 + W^2         # replace H with W/2
D^2 = W^2/94^2 + W^2         # apply square to numerator/denominator
D^2 = W^2(1+1/94^2)          # factorize to W^2   
D^2 = W^2(94^2+1)/94^2       # factorize to 1/94^2 
D^2 x 94^2/(94^2+1) = W^2    # divide by (94^2+1)/94^2
94D/√(94^2+1) = W            # square root
```

This gives you the scaled width (W), you can apply `H = W/94` to that to get the scaled height.  D^2 can be computed from the coordinates: `(lon1-lon2)^2 + (lat1-lat2)^2`

Note that this only gives you the size of the pink rectangle's sides (i.e. the scaling calculation).  You still have to do a bit more math to get the actual coordinates of the corners.